# Axios not receive response and error of the server Node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

i'm trying do a request `POST` using `axios.js` but the `axios` not is working, it not give the `response` or `error`, the console.log stay empty when i do the request, i dont know why. someone know?

My request `axios.js`:

```js
handleLogin = () => {
  this.setState({
    loading: true
  })

  axios.post("/login", {
      body: JSON.stringify({
        ...this.state
      })
    })
    .then(response =>
      localStorage.setItem('user-token', response.token),
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      })
    )
    .catch(error =>
      console.log(error),
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      })
    )
};
```

My `middleware`(isManager):

```js
const {
  findByMail
} = require('../data/acl/acl.model');

module.exports =
  async function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    const acl = await findByMail(req.body.username);

    if (acl && acl.role === "MANAGER") {
      next()
    } else {
      return res.status(401).send({
        message: "ERROR: YOU DONT HAVE ACCESS"
      })
    }
  }
```

My `route` that `axios` use:

```js
const isbmer = passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {
  session: false
});

router.post('/', [isManager, isbmer], (req, res) => {
  let id = req.user.ibmSerialNumber;
  const email = req.user.preferredIdentity;
  const name = req.user.cn;

  const json = {
    id,
    email,
    name
  };
  const expiresIn = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'local' ? '365d' : '10h';

  const token = jwt.sign(json, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn
  });


  res.status(200).send({
    auth: true,
    token
  });
});
```

Someone help me?When i do the request, nothing work..

Comment: You don't do a `console.log` in the function given to `then`, so maybe the request is successful?

Comment: Hello Tholle, no, the request no is successful :(

Comment: in axios you post to /login but your route is '/'. And also let id = req.user.ibmSerialNumber; can you print out your id, to see if you have it. If you have body-parser middleware for your express app, you do not need to do this body: JSON.stringify({ ...this.state }), you only need to post {...this.state} to your endpoint. In your route, you can access the object by req.body

Comment: Thanks, the `resposne`i receive but the error not, just the mesage default `Error: Request failed with status code 401` @dnp1204